# Why does git sign with GPG keys rather than using SSH keys?

Tags: git, digital-signature, ssh-keys, public-key, gpg-signature

What are the differences between SSH and GPG asymmetric keys and why does git support signing with GPG rather than using the SSH agent?

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/120706

Comment: That post doesn't quite answer my main question. I understand SSH is used for auth, but why can't a (probably different) key managed with the SSH agent sign the commit rather than GPG?

Comment: Indeed, but if you read it and (and its references) you will see that it is theoretically possible, it's just not *convenient*. In addition, PGP has extra features (not that Git uses them directly—Git itself is just invokes some external software—but things like key revocation are useful in these contexts).

Comment: Thanks, this complements the top answer here.

Comment: Note: Aug. 2022, [GitHub does support SSH commit verification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72852713/6309)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Update Sept. 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73652125/6309): 1Password supports generating and storing an SSH key for Git commit signature, recognized by GitHub.

---

Update 2021:

OpenSSH 8.2+ is available (packaged for instance in [Git For Windows 2.33.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.1.windows.1)), and "[it is now possible to sign arbitrary data with your SSH keys](https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/ssh_signatures?s=09)" ([Andrew Ayer](https://www.agwa.name/)), including commits in Git.

Andrew points to [`git/git` PR 1041 "ssh signing: Add commit & tag signing/verification via SSH keys using ssh-keygen"](https://github.com/git/git/pull/1041), [now with Git 2.34](https://github.blog/2021-11-15-highlights-from-git-2-34/#tidbits) (Nov. 2021)

[`gpg.format`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384754/6309) will have a new value "`ssh`"

> set `gpg.format = ssh` and `user.signingkey` to a ssh public key string (like from an authorized_keys file) and commits/tags can be signed using the private key from your ssh-agent.

Andrew adds:

> Always be wary of repurposing cryptographic keys for a different protocol. If not done carefully, there's a **risk of cross-protocol attacks**.
>
> For example, if the structure of the messages signed by Git is similar to the structure of SSH protocol messages, an attacker might be able to forge Git artifacts by misappropriating the signature from an SSH transcript.
>
> Fortunately, the structure of SSH protocol messages and the structure of messages signed by ssh-keygen are dissimilar enough that there is no risk of confusion.

That comes from:

Git 2.34 (Q4 2021): use ssh public crypto for object and push-cert signing.

See [commit 1bfb57f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1bfb57f642d34dc4b65be3602bb429abd9f32b58), [commit f265f2d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f265f2d630c498fd256d5da9d8b742efaf0cba8c), [commit 3326a78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3326a783f1cb309d438adea3d94a0448c4a21304), [commit facca53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/facca53ac3c2e8a5e2a4fe54c9c15de656c72de1), [commit 4838f62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4838f62c8caffbfe5d7d39cad4e8aeb2a2d57da8), [commit fd9e226](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd9e226776d1874af36b6b02fb2002b917af42fa), [commit 29b3157](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29b315778e958417a411f02b6d4b5a0fc9d731e2), [commit 64625c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64625c728fc281181e6dc6c0b8b538f0fbe47a30), [commit b5726a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5726a5d9cabba0bd8fb6c1b25a887bc7ea4650d) (10 Sep 2021) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 18c6653](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18c6653da0be924f83415f987d76f6813b81f086), 25 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ssh signing`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/facca53ac3c2e8a5e2a4fe54c9c15de656c72de1): verify signatures using ssh-keygen
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Fabian Stelzer</sup>

> To verify a ssh signature we first call `ssh-keygen -Y find-principal` to look up the signing principal by their public key from the `allowedSignersFile`.
> If the key is found then we do a verify.
> Otherwise we only validate the signature but can not verify the signers identity.
>
> Verification uses the `gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile` (see `ssh-keygen(1)` "ALLOWED SIGNERS") which contains valid public keys and a principal (usually `user@domain`).
> Depending on the environment this file can be managed by the individual developer or for example generated by the central repository server from known ssh keys with push access.
> This file is usually stored outside the repository, but if the repository only allows signed commits/pushes, the user might choose to store it in the repository.
>
> To revoke a key put the public key without the principal prefix into `gpg.ssh.revocationKeyring` or generate a KRL (see `ssh-keygen(1)` "KEY REVOCATION LISTS").
> The same considerations about who to trust for verification as with the `allowedSignersFile` apply.
>
> Using SSH CA Keys with these files is also possible.
> Add "`cert-authority`" as key option between the principal and the key to mark it as a CA and all keys signed by it as valid for this CA.
> See "CERTIFICATES" in `ssh-keygen(1)`.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/facca53ac3c2e8a5e2a4fe54c9c15de656c72de1/Documentation/config/gpg.txt#L42-L76):

> ### `gpg.ssh.allowedSignersFile`
>
> A file containing ssh public keys which you are willing to trust.
> The file consists of one or more lines of principals followed by an ssh
> public key.
> e.g.: `user1@example.com,user2@example.com ssh-rsa AAAAX1...`
> See `ssh-keygen(1)` "ALLOWED SIGNERS" for details.
> The principal is only used to identify the key and is available when
> verifying a signature.
>
> SSH has no concept of trust levels like gpg does. To be able to differentiate
> between valid signatures and trusted signatures the trust level of a signature
> verification is set to `fully` when the public key is present in the `allowedSignersFile`.
> Otherwise the trust level is `undefined` and git verify-commit/tag will fail.
>
> This file can be set to a location outside of the repository and every developer
> maintains their own trust store. A central repository server could generate this
> file automatically from ssh keys with push access to verify the code against.
> In a corporate setting this file is probably generated at a global location
> from automation that already handles developer ssh keys.
>
> A repository that only allows signed commits can store the file
> in the repository itself using a path relative to the top-level of the working tree.
> This way only committers with an already valid key can add or change keys in the keyring.
>
> Using a SSH CA key with the cert-authority option
> (see `ssh-keygen(1)` "CERTIFICATES") is also valid.
>
> ### `gpg.ssh.revocationFile`
>
> Either a SSH KRL or a list of revoked public keys (without the principal prefix).
> See `ssh-keygen(1)` for details.
> If a public key is found in this file then it will always be treated
> as having trust level "never" and signatures will show as invalid.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), extend the signing of objects with SSH keys and learn to pay attention to the key validity time range when verifying.

See [commit 50992f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50992f96c546ebdc0c149660f6baa948739888d9), [commit 122842f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/122842fd93eefadac237cfd73a4227b65c8b78ee), [commit dd3aa41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd3aa418aa109ff3697290ba89b626c3a4b36883), [commit 4bbf378](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bbf3780ff2c485b1d0781d58b26e01f75dffcc1), [commit 6393c95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6393c956f4e7061d6b19981bd8cd28ef037b911e), [commit 30770aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30770aa9817a5ea3886377cce66c264ab03c6854), [commit 0276943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02769437e1421d837f6de27cfb5c14087cfec8dd), [commit cafd345](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cafd34522f13e66b35bfcf00c04bc82f685a8ce9), [commit 5a2c1c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a2c1c0deeef3b2980827687b95e4446e1078eb3) (09 Dec 2021) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d2f0b72](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2f0b7275998ebeaa15e48ce0180c466e1d77ec4), 21 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ssh signing`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6393c956f4e7061d6b19981bd8cd28ef037b911e): make verify-commit consider key lifetime
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Fabian Stelzer</sup>

> If valid-before/after dates are configured for this signatures key in the `allowedSigners` file then the verification should check if the key was valid at the time the commit was made.
> This allows for graceful key rollover and revoking keys without invalidating all previous commits.
> This feature needs openssh > 8.8.
> Older ssh-keygen versions will simply ignore this flag and use the current time.
> Strictly speaking this feature is available in 8.7, but since 8.7 has a bug that makes it unusable in another needed call we require 8.8.
>
> Timestamp information is present on most invocations of `check_signature`.
> However signer ident is not.
> We will need the signer email / name to be able to implement "Trust on first use" functionality later.
> Since the payload contains all necessary information we can parse it from there.
> The caller only needs to provide us some info about the payload by setting `payload_type` in the `signature_check` struct.
>
> - Add `payload_type` field & enum and `payload_timestamp` to struct `signature_check
> - Populate the timestamp when not already set if we know about the payload type
> - Pass `-Overify-time={payload_timestamp}` in the users timezone to all ssh-keygen verification calls
> - Set the payload type when verifying commits
> - Add tests for expired, not yet valid and keys having a commit date outside of key validity as well as within

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6393c956f4e7061d6b19981bd8cd28ef037b911e/Documentation/config/gpg.txt#L67-L71):

> Since OpensSSH 8.8 this file allows specifying a key lifetime using valid-after &
> valid-before options.
>
> Git will mark signatures as valid if the signing key was
> valid at the time of the signatures creation.
>
> This allows users to change a
> signing key without invalidating all previously made signatures.

---

And, still with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), the cryptographic signing using ssh keys can specify literal keys for keytypes whose name do not begin with the "`ssh-`" prefix by using the "`key::`" prefix mechanism
(e.g. "`key::ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`").

See [commit 3b4b5a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b4b5a793a36d1e92114ff929eb7d15d55d45a96), [commit 350a251](https://github.com/git/git/commit/350a2518c8ea4f42934b4d6f3466d2815efff97f) (19 Nov 2021) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ee1dc49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee1dc493d10d814ceba1a551d9a185b9da627ad8), 21 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ssh signing`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/350a2518c8ea4f42934b4d6f3466d2815efff97f): support non ssh-* keytypes
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Fabian Stelzer</sup>

> The `user.signingKey` config for ssh signing supports either a path to a file containing the key or for the sake of convenience a literal string with the ssh public key.
>
> To differentiate between those two cases we check if the first few characters contain "`ssh-`" which is unlikely to be the start of a path.
> ssh supports other key types which are not prefixed with "`ssh-`" and will currently be treated as a file path and therefore fail to load.
> To remedy this we move the prefix check into its own function and introduce the prefix `key::` for literal ssh keys.
> This way we don't need to add new key types when they become available.
> The existing `ssh-` prefix is retained for compatibility with current user configs but removed from the official documentation to discourage its use.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/350a2518c8ea4f42934b4d6f3466d2815efff97f/Documentation/config/user.txt#L39-L48):

> If `gpg.format` is set to `ssh` this can contain the path to either
> your private ssh key or the public key when ssh-agent is used.
> Alternatively it can contain a public key prefixed with `key::`
> directly (e.g.: "`key::ssh-rsa XXXXXX identifier`").
>
> The private key
> needs to be available via ssh-agent.
> If not set git will call
> `gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand` (e.g.: "`ssh-add -L`") and try to use the
> first key available.
>
> For backward compatibility, a raw key which
> begins with "`ssh-`", such as "`ssh-rsa XXXXXX identifier`", is treated
> as "`key::ssh-rsa XXXXXX identifier`", but this form is deprecated;
> use the `key::` form instead.

---

"[`git merge $signed_tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cde28af37b19e07139ebb6a355d742e763b7a235/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> started to drop the tag message from the default merge message it uses by accident, which has been corrected with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

See [commit c39fc06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c39fc06b999305963600358f3f5e99698440cad2) (10 Jan 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cde28af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cde28af37b19e07139ebb6a355d742e763b7a235), 12 Jan 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fmt-merge-msg`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c39fc06b999305963600358f3f5e99698440cad2): prevent use-after-free with signed tags
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Linus Torvalds</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> When merging a signed tag, `fmt_merge_msg_sigs()` is responsible for populating the body of the merge message with the names of the signed tags, their signatures, and the validity of those signatures.
>
> In [0276943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02769437e1421d837f6de27cfb5c14087cfec8dd) ("ssh signing: use sigc struct to pass payload", 2021-12-09, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2f0b7275998ebeaa15e48ce0180c466e1d77ec4) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/597af311a2899bfd6640b9b107622c5795d5f998)), `check_signature()` was taught to pass the object payload via the sigc struct instead of passing the payload buffer separately.
>
> In effect, [0276943](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02769437e1421d837f6de27cfb5c14087cfec8dd) causes `buf`, and `sigc.payload` to point at the same region in memory.
> This causes a problem for `fmt_tag_signature()`, which wants to read from this location, since it is freed beforehand by `signature_check_clear()` (which frees it via sigc's `payload` member).
>
> That makes the subsequent use in `fmt_tag_signature()` a use-after-free.
>
> As a result, merge messages did not contain the body of any signed tags.
> Luckily, they tend not to contain garbage, either, since the result of strstr()-ing the object buffer in `fmt_tag_signature()` is guarded:
>
> ```c
> const char *tag_body = strstr(buf, "\n\n");
> if (tag_body) {
>   tag_body += 2;
>   strbuf_add(tagbuf, tag_body, buf + len - tag_body);
> }
> ```
>
> Resolve this by waiting to call `signature_check_clear()` until after its contents can be safely discarded.
> Harden ourselves against any future regressions in this area by making sure we can find signed tag messages in the output of fmt-merge-msg, too.

---

Original answer (2017): The very first notion of signing *anything* in Git was referenced in [commit ec4465a, Git v0.99, Apr. 2005](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ec4465adb38d21966acdc9510ff15c0fe4539468) (pretty much from the very beginning)

```c
/**
 * A signature file has a very simple fixed format: three lines
 * of "object <sha1>" + "type <typename>" + "tag <tagname>",
 * followed by some free-form signature that git itself doesn't
 * care about, but that can be verified with gpg or similar.
 **/
```

So your question has legs.

The very first signed commit used gpg, but could have used anything else ([commit 65f0d0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65f0d0ee4627dd0f0468ceded38677076d78feb5)):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
object=${2:-$(cat .git/HEAD)}
type=$(cat-file -t $object) || exit 1
( echo -e "object $object\ntype $type\ntag $1\n"; cat ) > .tmp-tag
rm -f .tmp-tag.asc
gpg -bsa .tmp-tag && cat .tmp-tag.asc >> .tmp-tag
git-mktag < .tmp-tag
#rm .tmp-tag .tmp-tag.sig
```

Technically, you can use [gpg in place of ssh](https://superuser.com/a/390176/141). I haven't seen often the reverse though.
But you can use [an ssh key-pair be used with PGP/GPG](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/66482).
That means the first validation script might still work ([commit f336e71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f336e71f86560df3503c1da1f68635a184af28a9))... except it expected a PGP comment:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
GIT_DIR=${GIT_DIR:-.git}

tag=$1
[ -f "$GIT_DIR/refs/tags/$tag" ] && tag=$(cat "$GIT_DIR/refs/tags/$tag")

git-cat-file tag $tag > .tmp-vtag || exit 1
cat .tmp-vtag | sed '/-----BEGIN PGP/Q' | gpg --verify .tmp-vtag -
rm -f .tmp-vtag
```

So, "Why does git sign with GPG keys rather than using SSH keys?": it is what GPG is meant to do, as opposed to SSH, [which cannot do with openssh alone (it needs openssl)](https://superuser.com/a/308130/141).

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119932/why-does-git-sign-with-gpg-keys-rather-than-using-ssh-keys/45120525#comment77216257_45119932) by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek), using SSH would be theoretically possible, it's just not convenient.

> In addition, PGP has extra features (not that Git uses them directly—Git itself is just invokes some external software—but things like key revocation are useful in these contexts).

---

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) explains `ssh.defaultKeyCommand`:

See [commit ce18a30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce18a30bb78720d90df42b9d9ee6b8b7dd33d7e6) (08 Jun 2022) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 686790f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/686790f6c1a3150ced65fdd8e3278129a516cd9a), 15 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`gpg docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce18a30bb78720d90df42b9d9ee6b8b7dd33d7e6): explain better use of ssh.defaultKeyCommand
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Fabian Stelzer</sup>

> Using `ssh-add -L` for `gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand` is *not* a good recommendation.
> It might switch keys depending on the order of known keys and it only supports `ssh-*` and no `ecdsa` or other keys.
>
> Clarify that we expect a literal key prefixed by `key::`, give valid example use cases and refer to `user.signingKey` as the preferred option.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce18a30bb78720d90df42b9d9ee6b8b7dd33d7e6/Documentation/config/gpg.txt#L39-L44):

> signature is requested. On successful exit a valid ssh public key
> prefixed with `key::` is expected in the first line of its output.
> This allows for a script doing a dynamic lookup of the correct public
> key when it is impractical to statically configure `user.signingKey`.
> For example when keys or SSH Certificates are rotated frequently or
> selection of the right key depends on external factors unknown to git.

And, with [commit ce18a30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce18a30bb78720d90df42b9d9ee6b8b7dd33d7e6) (08 Jun 2022) by [Fabian Stelzer (`FStelzer`)](https://github.com/FStelzer).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 686790f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/686790f6c1a3150ced65fdd8e3278129a516cd9a), 15 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`686790f6c1`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/686790f6c1a3150ced65fdd8e3278129a516cd9a):Merge branch 'fs/ssh-default-key-command-doc'

> Doc update: `fs/ssh-default-key-command-doc`: gpg docs: explain better use of `ssh.defaultKeyCommand`
>
> ### `gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand`:
>
> This command that will be run when `user.signingkey` is not set and a ssh signature is requested.
> On successful exit a valid ssh public key prefixed with `key::` is expected in the first line of its output.
> This allows for a script doing a dynamic lookup of the correct public key when it is impractical to statically configure `user.signingKey`.
>
> For example when keys or SSH Certificates are rotated frequently or selection of the right key depends on external factors unknown to git.

Comment: Thank you, this answer really adds the context I needed to understand.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you should NOT use `ssh` for signing commits is the one of the common rules of cryptography: You should not use the same keys for different applications/use cases.

In SSH you use a key for authentication, but that is something different then the signing your commits. For this, GPG is much more suited as it is already widely used for signing emails, files and so on.

Comment: You can use a different `ssh` key for signing your commits.

Answer (score 3):

One likely reason is that not everybody using git is using ssh.

You can create a git repo and never have it leave your local disk. You can use the git protocol, or http, or https, or network filesystems... none of those things involve ssh, but you can still sign commits, because that happens independent of any network transport or other push/pull sharing of your commits.

Comment: That's a valid point, but my thought is that SSH and its toolset is more ubiquitous, so why not leverage it? I began signing commits and had to download the GPG toolset, which led me to this question. The top answer explains why.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, work is underway to allow the use of SSH keys for signature (and verification): https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.1041.git.git.1625559593910.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/

This will presumably be valuable in limited (eg corporate) contexts where git is currently the *only* reason to deal with GPG, and sticking with SSH only could save some key-management and software-management overhead for users...

Comment: Good point. I believe this is available with Git 2.34. I have updated [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120525/6309) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this update. Your note about the corporate use case is an important aside because it hints at the problem of determining who is the **authority** and has final say on the identity in question. GPG was designed to be decentralized by encouraging the distributed "web-of-trust" (https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN554) to serve as the authority, not a single person or authority. It makes sense that `git` would use `GPG` because it shares the decentralized design discipline.