# git commit not signing properly with GPG on OSX

Tags: git, macos, gnupg

I've been attempting to get `git` working with a `gpg` key and after lots of searching and reading of posts, the only thing that works for me is this:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gpgsm
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gpg /usr/local/bin/gpgsm
```

This tricks `git` into running a `gpg` command instead of a `gpgsm` command as seen here:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git commit -S -m"test"
21:24:25.489158 git.c:418               trace: built-in: git commit -S -mtest
21:24:25.493338 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: gpgsm --status-fd=2 -bsau myKey
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I can't find any additional information on why `git` is running a `gpgsm` command, as running the command by itself yields:

```
gpgsm --status-fd=2 -bsau myKey
gpgsm: can't sign using 'myKey': No public key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR 1 myKey
[GNUPG:] INV_RECP 1 myKey
```

Which seems to make sense as I read `gpg` and `gpgsm`'s DBs are seperate.

`gpgsm` keys don't appear to be what `git` wants to use either, based on their need for CN and DNS entries. Happy to be shown wrong here as I'd rather not use my symlink hack.

Environment details:

- gpg install via homebrew, version `2.2.11`
- Adding `no-tty` to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` actually made things worse for me.
- I've restarted after changes to ensure gpg agents die.
- The contents of `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` is: `pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry`

Comment: Is it your goal to use OpenPGP (the default `gpg` binary) or CMS (the `gpgsm` binary)? Also, which Git version are you using?

Comment: I'd like to use `gpg` as that appears to be what github supports, although I may be incorrect in assuming it doesn't support `gpgsm`. I am open to working with whatever gets to me to a spot where I don't need the symlink hack.

My git version is `2.20.0`.

Comment: If you use the plain `gpg` binary (without the symlink hack), what output do you get? Also, what output do you get with the real gpg if you run `touch /tmp/foo && gpg --status-fd=2 -bsa /tmp/foo` to sign an empty file?

Comment: Apologies for the bad formatting.

Output:

`gpg
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...`

Second command:

`touch /tmp/foo && gpg --status-fd=2 -bsa /tmp/foo
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 
FC660649664B0D5D12EE7B63B209F8077D754B33 0
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 
FC660649664B0D5D12EE7B63B209F8077D754B33 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 2111 curses 1.1.0 /dev/ttys006 xterm- 
256color -
[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED D 1 8 00 1545082985 
FC660649664B0D5D12EE7B63B209F8077D754B33`

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the problem when I stumbled upon [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384754) of git's `gpg.format` config. Apparently it supports both "opengpg" which runs `gpg` and "x509" which runs `gpgsm`. Running the following command resulted in `git commit -S` using `gpg` instead of `gpgsm`.

```
git config --global gpg.format openpgp
```

you can confirm the format is what you expect by looking at the full config via

```
git config -l --show-origin | grep gpg.format
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Git's trying to use `gpgsm`, it's likely that you have some sort of configuration that's set to use `gpgsm` as the program to sign things. You probably want to run `git config -l --show-origin` and see if there's an option set to make Git use `gpgsm`. You can search for `gpg`, as all of the options are set under that top-level section.

Comment: That's my thinking as well, but I just can't find where it is set. Running the provided command shows `gpg` as my program both globally and within my test repo, while that `git` debug command continues to try and run `gpgsm`. I also get no `grep` hits for `gpgsm` when running the `git` global config showing. Very strange. I am going to see about comparing to some colleague setups.

Thank you for the assistance though; this is going to be something odd and I'll be sure to update if/when I find it.