# Git GPG Signing Bad Signature

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, signature, gnupg

I am trying to enable gpg commit signing on my mac. I have successfully signed one commit and then tried to do it again and ever since I can't get it to work properly again.
Every time it says Bad Signature even though the KEY ID is the same.

I can normally sign regular text files etc. without problems - git is the only one making such weird exceptions.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks!

```bash
commit 2cce84252649442b2b1700986f969fd70d8d7dbc (HEAD -> move-to-docker)
gpg: Signatur vom Di 14 Jun 07:30:19 2022 CEST
gpg:                mittels EDDSA-Schlüssel C84C8DAA9C25D70F553262EE4584796C0B3C2855
gpg: FALSCHE Signatur von "Nick Wassermann (Root SSH User) <nick.wassermann@mail.at>" [unbekannt]
Author: Nick Wassermann <nick.wassermann@mail.at>
Date:   Tue Jun 14 07:30:19 2022 +0200

    tte

commit 3ad84f737e7d1f42907cb55b11482c7d5558adaf
gpg: Signatur vom Mo 13 Jun 09:23:06 2022 CEST
gpg:                mittels EDDSA-Schlüssel C84C8DAA9C25D70F553262EE4584796C0B3C2855
gpg: Korrekte Signatur von "Nick Wassermann (Root SSH User) <nick.wassermann@mail.at>" [unbekannt]
gpg: WARNUNG: Dieser Schlüssel trägt keine vertrauenswürdige Signatur!
gpg:          Es gibt keinen Hinweis, daß die Signatur wirklich dem vorgeblichen Besitzer gehört.
Haupt-Fingerabdruck  = 90C6 F702 31A1 7582 98B3  C94C 1779 A12E 703B D538
Unter-Fingerabdruck  = C84C 8DAA 9C25 D70F 5532  62EE 4584 796C 0B3C 2855
Author: Nick Wassermann <nick.wassermann@mail.at>
Date:   Mon Jun 13 09:23:06 2022 +0200

    added comment
```

Comment: Copy pasting is much preferred to screenshots.

Comment: Try running with `GIT_TRACE=1` or `GIT_TRACE2=1` and see if something differs in the `gpg` invocations Git makes.

Comment: @philb running in the CLI and then again `git log --show-signature` ?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the [GitLab sign commit (with GPG)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/gpg_signed_commits/) process:

> To sign commits, you must configure both your local machine and your GitLab account:
>
> - Create a GPG key.
> - Add a GPG key to your account.
> - Associate your GPG key with Git.
> - Sign your Git commits.

Note the email must match a verified email address in your GitLab account.
And check your keyID (`git config --global user.signingkey`)

As an alternative, you can also consider [signing your commits with X.509 certificates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/x509_signed_commits/).

Comment: I did and the first commit got correctly signed by git but the second one gets signed but git always complaints bad signature (`FALSCHE Signatur` its german..)

Comment: @NickWassermann OK. Maybe this is because you have [not trusted your key yet](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/147447)?

Comment: when I run `gpg --export-ownertrust` I get the Fingerprint with the trust level of 6. The part that drives me crazy is that the EDSA-Key values are the same.

Comment: @NickWassermann Try and [edit your key](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html), just to double-check its trust level.

Comment: I did but unfortunately it didn't change the outcome of trying to sing a commit

Comment: @NickWassermann What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245586/discussion-between-vonc-and-nick-wassermann).

Answer (score 0):

See [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#sign-commits-with-your-ssh-key) (December 2022) proposes an alternative approach, simpler than GPG:

> ### Sign commits with your SSH key
>
> Signing commits just got a lot simpler. Use SSH keys
> [to sign commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/ssh_signed_commits/),
> and provide others with confidence that a **Verified** commit was authored by you.
>
> Previous methods for signing commits required a GPG key or an X.509
> certificate, neither of which can be used to sign in to GitLab.
> Adding support for commit signing with SSH keys now makes it possible
> to reuse your authentication key pair to also sign your commits. If you
> already authenticate into GitLab with an SSH key, add three lines of code
> to your local Git configuration and all your future commits will be signed.
>
> By default, all SSH keys currently in your profile can be used for
> both authentication and signing commits. To use a key for only
> one of the purposes, upload a new key.
>
> [image: sign]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/ssh_signed_commits/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/343879).