# I've been trying to reconfigure my SSH key

Tags: git, github, git-bash, ssh-keys

I keep getting the following error:

```bash
git commit -sam "blah blah blah"
fatal: either user.signingkey or gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand needs to be configured
```

I just updated Git completely trying to figure this out, so it's completely up to date, and then I successfully added all of my usual configurations to the new version now running in Git Bash.  I've repeatedly gone to Github's SSH key generator and followed the directions one by one.  AND AFTER ALL THAT, I'M STILL GETTING THIS ERROR.

I am unable to make commits ANYWHERE on my local machine (Git Bash, Terminal, GitKraken; I even broke down and tried Github Desktop), much less signed, annotated commits, as is my habit.  I removed the expired keys from my Github account.  I DON'T KNOW WHAT ELSE TO DO.

[image: I'm about to lose my mind.]

Comment: I wouldn't post that ASCII image, you can recreate the key from it

Comment: I removed the image.

Comment: The old image is still visible in the history of this question.

Comment: The only safe course of action for secret leaks like that is to immediately deactivate the secret (i.e. remove it from github or any other site where you use it and then delete it).

Comment: How do I delete it in the history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing together the concepts of ssh keys (which are somewhat generalized and apply across all of ssh, and which you can use to authenticate yourself to GitHub) and Git's *signed commits* (and signed annotated tags).  These are different, although they use related mechanisms.

In particular, to use an ssh key to *sign a Git commit*, you must:

- configure your ssh locally so that it can sign commits (this may or may not already be supported depending on your OpenSSH version);
- tell Git *how* to use your ssh to sign commits (this depends on your ssh version); and
- tell Git *to* use ssh to sign commits.

None of these three steps use or require anything on *GitHub*.  But this is what is failing here: you have not set up `user.signingkey` or `gpg.ssh.defaultKeyCommand` in Git, which is where that second bullet point comes in.  (You're already doing the third one, but Git doesn't know *how* to run your ssh yet!)  You'll need to figure out how to get Git to invoke the right commands on your system (which will depend somewhat on your OS and OpenSSH version).

Once you have such signed commits, however, these digital signatures are useful only to you, not to anyone else, *unless* you have spread the key(s) involved in these digital signatures.  This is where you get GitHub involved.

See [How do I sign git commits using my existing ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72844616/1256452) and particularly VonC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45120525/1256452) to [Why does git sign with GPG keys rather than using SSH keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45119932/1256452), to see how to do the first part.  See both VonC's and other answers, particularly [Jakuje's here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126508/1256452), for some cautions involving using ssh keys here.

I don't know any of the GitHub side details here, but VonC's answers have more.

In general, it's a lot easier to use GPG for signing commits and/or annotated tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ssh key an want to sign your commits using SSH

Try this: {change `jayrizzo` or `the path to your public key` to your name/path.}

```bash
# windows
git config --global user.signingkey C:\Users\jayrizzo\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

# linux
git config --global user.signingkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then after running the above, try making the commit again.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72852713/1896134

Cheers!